# A query to check the first 2 chars of a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if it's possible to make a query to check the first two chars of a string?

For example, I have these entries in my table:

```
toto
topo
poto
```

I want to get the entries when the two first chars are `to`.

Answer (score 7):

As simple as this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE `name` LIKE "to%"
```

`to%` means that the word should start by `to` and can be followed by other character

Comment: " vs ' on the to?  I've not seen the " syntax for strings in mysql before.  but it works: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html

Comment: You can use single or double quote, both are totally fine.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE RowName LIKE 'to%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select fieldName
from tableName
where fieldName like 'to%'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to check the first 2 chars of a string but return all results..

```
SELECT fieldname, 
       if(left(fieldname,2)='XX',1,0) as XCheck
FROM tablename
```